# Improved lightbox2-fork

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a nice lightbox2-fork, which I tried to improve.  After about six hours of work the code passes jslint.  I also tried to change variable names for better understanding of what they are for.

What else can be improved there?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6xyn/) (yet unmodified but working CSS)

[lpaste](http://lpaste.net/107441)

```
$(function () {
  "use strict";

  var border,
    borderColor,
    content,
    contentHeight,
    counter,
    counterContainer,
    frameHeight,
    frameWidth,
    ie9,
    iOS,
    isNext,
    isPrev,
    items,
    keyNavigationDisabled,
    margins,
    nextItem,
    overlay,
    overlayColor,
    preload,
    prevItem,
    title,
    titleContainer,
    top,
    url,
    vcore,
    vwrap,
    windowHeight,
    wrapAround;

  // center on load
  function updateoverlay(notopzero) {
    notopzero = notopzero || false;

    if (notopzero !== true) {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }

    titleContainer.html(title);
    content.find(">:first-child").addClass("lightbox");
    $(".lightbox").css("width", frameWidth).css("height", frameHeight).css("padding", border).css("background", borderColor);
    contentHeight = content.outerHeight();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if (contentHeight + 80 < windowHeight) {
      margins = (windowHeight - contentHeight) / 2;
      content.css("margin-bottom", margins);
      content.css("margin-top", margins);
    } else {
      content.css("margin-bottom", "40px");
      content.css("margin-top", "40px");
    }

    content.animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  }

  // center on resize
  function updateoverlayresize() {
    if ($(".vbox-content").length) {
      contentHeight = content.height();
      windowHeight = $(window).height();

      if (contentHeight + 80 < windowHeight) {
        margins = (windowHeight - contentHeight) / 2;
        content.css("margin-bottom", margins);
        content.css("margin-top", margins);
      } else {
        content.css("margin-bottom", "40px");
        content.css("margin-top", "40px");
      }
    }
  }

  // load Ajax
  function loadAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false
    }).done(function (msg) {
      content.html('<div class="vbox-inline">' + msg + "</div>");
      updateoverlay(true);
    }).fail(function () {
      content.html('<div class="vbox-inline"><p>Error retrieving contents, please retry</div>');
      updateoverlay(true);
    });
  }

  // load iframe
  function loadIframe() {
    content.html('<iframe class="vbox-frame" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
  // valid only for iframes in same url
  //  $(".vbox-frame").load(function () {
    updateoverlay();
  //  });
  }

  // load Vimeo
  function loadVimeo() {
    var part = url.split("/"),
      videoid = part[part.length - 1];

    content.html('<iframe class="vbox-frame" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoid + '"></iframe>');
    updateoverlay();
  }

  // load YouTube
  function loadYoutube() {
    var part = url.split("/"),
      videoid = part[part.length - 1];

    content.html('<iframe class="vbox-frame" allowfullscreen src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoid + '"></iframe>');
    updateoverlay();
  }

  // load inline element
  function loadInline() {
    content.html('<div class="vbox-inline">' + $(url).html() + "</div>");
    updateoverlay();
  }

  // preload images
  function preloadFirst() {
    preload = $(".vbox-content").find("img");
    preload.one("load", function () {
      updateoverlay();
    }).each(function () {
      if (this.complete) {
        $(this).load();
      }
    });
  }

  $.fn.extend({
    vbox: function (overwriteOptions) {

      var defaults = {
        border: "0",
        borderColor: "#ffffff",
        counter: true,
        frameHeight: "",
        frameWidth: "",
        wrapAround: false
      },
        options = $.extend(defaults, overwriteOptions);

      return this.each(function () {
        var obj = $(this);

        obj.addClass("vbox-item");
        obj.data("frameWidth", options.frameWidth);
        obj.data("frameHeight", options.frameHeight);
        obj.data("border", options.border);
        obj.data("borderColor", options.borderColor);
        obj.data("counter", options.counter);
        obj.data("wrapAround", options.wrapAround);

        iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);

        ie9 = ((document.all && !window.atob) ? true : false);

        obj.click(function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();

          obj = $(this);
          overlayColor = obj.data("overlay");
          frameWidth = obj.data("frameWidth");
          frameHeight = obj.data("frameHeight");
          border = obj.data("border");
          borderColor = obj.data("borderColor");
          isNext = false;
          isPrev = false;
          keyNavigationDisabled = false;
          url = obj.attr("href");
          top = $(window).scrollTop();
          top = -top;

          // check if there is a next or previous image
          function checknav() {
            counter = obj.data("counter");
            wrapAround = obj.data("wrapAround");
            items = $('.vbox-item[data-vbox="' + obj.data("vbox") + '"]');

            if (items.length > 0 && counter === true) {
              counterContainer.html(items.index(obj) + 1 + " / " + items.length);
              counterContainer.fadeIn();
            } else {
              counterContainer.fadeOut();
            }

            nextItem = items.eq(items.index(obj) + 1);
            prevItem = items.eq(items.index(obj) - 1);

            if (obj.attr("title")) {
              title = obj.attr("title");
              titleContainer.fadeIn();
            } else {
              title = "";
              titleContainer.fadeOut();
            }

            if (wrapAround === true) {
              isNext = true;
              isPrev = true;
              if (nextItem.length < 1) {
                nextItem = items.eq(0);
              }
              if (items.index(obj) < 1) {
                prevItem = items.eq(items.index(items.length));
              }
            } else {
              if (nextItem.length > 0) {
                $(".vbox-next").css("display", "block");
                isNext = true;
              } else {
                $(".vbox-next").css("display", "none");
                isNext = false;
              }
              if (items.index(obj) > 0) {
                $(".vbox-prev").css("display", "block");
                isPrev = true;
              } else {
                $(".vbox-prev").css("display", "none");
                isPrev = false;
              }
            }
          }

          $("body").wrapInner('<div class="vwrap"></div>');

          vwrap = $(".vwrap");

          vcore = '<div class="vbox-overlay" style="background:' + overlayColor + '"><div class="vbox-preloader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div><div class="vbox-container"><div class="vbox-content"></div></div><div class="vbox-title"></div><div class="vbox-num">0/0</div><div class="vbox-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div class="vbox-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div><div class="vbox-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div></div>';

          $("body").append(vcore);

          //container = $(".vbox-container");
          content = $(".vbox-content");
          counterContainer = $(".vbox-num");
          overlay = $(".vbox-overlay");
          titleContainer = $(".vbox-title");

          content.html("");

          content.css("opacity", "0");

          checknav();

          overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight() + 130);

          if (ie9) {
            overlay.animate({opacity: 1}, 250, function () {
              overlay.css({
                "min-height": $(window).outerHeight(),
                height: "auto"
              });
              if (obj.data("type") === "iframe") {
                loadIframe();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "inline") {
                loadInline();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "ajax") {
                loadAjax();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                loadVimeo();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "youtube") {
                loadYoutube();
              } else {
                content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                preloadFirst();
              }
            });
          } else {
            overlay.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
              overlay.css({
                "min-height": $(window).outerHeight(),
                height: "auto"
              });
              if (obj.data("type") === "iframe") {
                loadIframe();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "inline") {
                loadInline();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "ajax") {
                loadAjax();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                loadVimeo();
              } else if (obj.data("type") === "youtube") {
                loadYoutube();
              } else {
                content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                preloadFirst();
              }
            });
            overlay.css("opacity", "1");
          }

          if (iOS) {
            vwrap.css({
              "opacity": "0",
              "position": "fixed",
              "top": top
            }).data("top", top);
          } else {
            vwrap.css({
              "position": "fixed",
              "top": top
            }).data("top", top);
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
          }

          // keyboard navigation
          $("body").keydown(function (e) {
            if (keyNavigationDisabled) {
              return;
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
              $(".vbox-close").click();
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 37 && isPrev === true) {
              border = prevItem.data("border");
              borderColor = prevItem.data("borderColor");
              frameWidth = prevItem.data("frameWidth");
              frameHeight = prevItem.data("frameHeight");
              keyNavigationDisabled = true;
              overlayColor = prevItem.data("overlay");
              url = prevItem.attr("href");

              if (prevItem.attr("title")) {
                title = prevItem.attr("title");
              } else {
                title = "";
              }

              if (overlayColor === undefined) {
                overlayColor = "";
              }

              overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight() + 130);

              content.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
                overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight()).css("background", overlayColor);

                if (prevItem.data("type") === "iframe") {
                  loadIframe();
                } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "inline") {
                  loadInline();
                } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "ajax") {
                  loadAjax();
                } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "youtube") {
                  loadYoutube();
                } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                  loadVimeo();
                } else {
                  content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                  preloadFirst();
                }

                obj = prevItem;

                checknav();

                keyNavigationDisabled = false;
              });
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 39 && isNext === true) {
              border = nextItem.data("border");
              borderColor = nextItem.data("borderColor");
              frameWidth = nextItem.data("frameWidth");
              frameHeight = nextItem.data("frameHeight");
              keyNavigationDisabled = true;
              overlayColor = nextItem.data("overlay");
              url = nextItem.attr("href");

              if (nextItem.attr("title")) {
                title = nextItem.attr("title");
              } else {
                title = "";
              }

              if (overlayColor === undefined) {
                overlayColor = "";
              }

              overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight() + 130);

              content.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
                overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight()).css("background", overlayColor);

                if (nextItem.data("type") === "iframe") {
                  loadIframe();
                } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "inline") {
                  loadInline();
                } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "ajax") {
                  loadAjax();
                } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "youtube") {
                  loadYoutube();
                } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                  loadVimeo();
                } else {
                  content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                  preloadFirst();
                }

                obj = nextItem;

                checknav();

                keyNavigationDisabled = false;
              });
            }
          });

          // next image
          $(".vbox-next").click(function () {
            border = nextItem.data("border");
            borderColor = nextItem.data("borderColor");
            frameWidth = nextItem.data("frameWidth");
            frameHeight = nextItem.data("frameHeight");
            overlayColor = nextItem.data("overlay");
            url = nextItem.attr("href");

            if (nextItem.attr("title")) {
              title = nextItem.attr("title");
            } else {
              title = "";
            }

            if (overlayColor === undefined) {
              overlayColor = "";
            }

            overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight() + 130);

            content.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
              overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight()).css("background", overlayColor);

              if (nextItem.data("type") === "iframe") {
                loadIframe();
              } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "inline") {
                loadInline();
              } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "ajax") {
                loadAjax();
              } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "youtube") {
                loadYoutube();
              } else if (nextItem.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                loadVimeo();
              } else {
                content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                preloadFirst();
              }

              obj = nextItem;

              checknav();
            });
          });

          // previous image
          $(".vbox-prev").click(function () {
            border = prevItem.data("border");
            borderColor = prevItem.data("borderColor");
            frameWidth = prevItem.data("frameWidth");
            frameHeight = prevItem.data("frameHeight");
            overlayColor = prevItem.data("overlay");
            url = prevItem.attr("href");

            if (prevItem.attr("title")) {
              title = prevItem.attr("title");
            } else {
              title = "";
            }

            if (overlayColor === undefined) {
              overlayColor = "";
            }

            overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight() + 130);

            content.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
              overlay.css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight()).css("background", overlayColor);

              if (prevItem.data("type") === "iframe") {
                loadIframe();
              } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "inline") {
                loadInline();
              } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "ajax") {
                loadAjax();
              } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "youtube") {
                loadYoutube();
              } else if (prevItem.data("type") === "vimeo") {
                loadVimeo();
              } else {
                content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
                preloadFirst();
              }

              obj = prevItem;

              checknav();
            });
          });

          // close
          $(".vbox-close, .vbox-overlay").click(function (e) {

            if (!$(e.target).is(".lightbox, .vbox-prev, .vbox-prev .fa, .vbox-next, .vbox-next .fa, .lightbox *")) {
              if (ie9) {
                overlay.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
                  overlay.remove();
                  $(".vwrap").children().unwrap();
                  $(window).scrollTop(-top);
                  keyNavigationDisabled = false;
                });
              } else {
                overlay.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");
                overlay.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
                  overlay.remove();

                  if (iOS) {
                    $(".vwrap").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
                      $(".vwrap").children().unwrap();
                      $(window).scrollTop(-top);
                    });
                    $(".vwrap").css("opacity", "1");
                  } else {
                    $(".vwrap").children().unwrap();
                    $(window).scrollTop(-top);
                  }

                  keyNavigationDisabled = false;
                });

                overlay.css("opacity", "0");
              }
            }
          });

          return false;
        });
      });
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function () {
    updateoverlayresize();
  });

});
```

Comment: Please don't updated the original embedded code based on answers.  You may still update the linked code.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question,

this code has a serious bit of copy pastage:

- Lines 328-365 are identical to 468-504
- Lines 375-412 are identical to 423-459

And, these 2 large blocks of code are very similar to each other ( `prevItem` <> `nextItem` ). You should DRY this up.

Also this block is repeated in the code:

```
if (prevItem.data("type") === "iframe") {
  loadIframe();
} else if (prevItem.data("type") === "inline") {
  loadInline();
} else if (prevItem.data("type") === "ajax") {
  loadAjax();
} else if (prevItem.data("type") === "youtube") {
  loadYoutube();
} else if (prevItem.data("type") === "vimeo") {
  loadVimeo();
} else {
  content.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
  preloadFirst();
}
```

I would say in general you need to re-review the code with DRYness in mind, this:

```
if (contentHeight + 80 < windowHeight) {
  margins = (windowHeight - contentHeight) / 2;
  content.css("margin-bottom", margins);
  content.css("margin-top", margins);
} else {
  content.css("margin-bottom", "40px");
  content.css("margin-top", "40px");
}
```

could be

```
if (contentHeight + 80 < windowHeight) {
  margins = (windowHeight - contentHeight) / 2;
} else {
  margins = '40px' ;
}
content.css("margin-bottom", margins);
content.css("margin-top", margins);
```

or if you are into ternaries:

```
margins = (contentHeight + 80 < windowHeight) ? (windowHeight - contentHeight) / 2 : '40px';
content.css("margin-bottom", margins);
content.css("margin-top", margins);
```

This piece of code is also copy pasted btw.

You should also clean up the commented code:

```
  // load iframe <- Seriously, how is this comment helping ??
  function loadIframe() {
    content.html('<iframe class="vbox-frame" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
  // valid only for iframes in same url
  //  $(".vbox-frame").load(function () {
    updateoverlay();
  //  });
  }
```

Should be

```
  function loadIframe() {
    content.html('<iframe class="vbox-frame" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
    updateoverlay();
  }
```

Also, consider, should `updateoverlay` be called in every single `loadxxx` function, or should it be called after the switch statement that calls these functions?

Finally. if you are working on naming; `updateoverlay` -> `updateOverlay` (lowerCamelCase)

Comment: Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6xyn/5/) – @konijn
What about all those variables in the beginning of the script?
What does the "return false;" on the very bottom of the script?

Comment: @fooness JsHint did not complain about unused variables so that is okay. I think the return false is part of an even handler, and thus standard fare.

Comment: Great, thanks. Would you have an ideas, on how I could improve this code-block, you posted as first code? That's also diffictult because I have not always prevItem, but also nextItem and some others.